# How to set a dynamic task as a defaultTask

Tags: boost, gradle

Sorry for the newbie question, but I have yet to see an example or question related to specifying [dynamic tasks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N1029B) as a defaultTask in a gradle project.

So, how do I specify the dynamic $boostLibName tasks as the defaultTasks?

#### build.gradle

```
defaultTasks 'whatgoeshere'

ext {
    // The boost directory, which changes according to version
    // there should be a better way to do this
    boostDir = './boost_1_53_0'

    // The list of boost libraries that we want to build
    boostLibs = ['smart_ptr', 'filesystem', 'array.hpp']
}


// Create a task to build each boost library
boostLibs.each { def boostLibName ->
    println boostLibName
    tasks.create(name: boostLibName, dependsOn: aBoostBcp, type: Exec) {

        workingDir project.boostDir

        def b2compiler = 'toolset=' + System.properties['boost_toolset']
        def b2target = '--with-' + boostLibName
        def cmd

        if(System.properties['platform'] == 'windows') {
            //on windows
            cmd = ['cmd', '/c', '.\\b2', b2compiler, b2target] 
        } else {
            //on unix and mac
            cmd = ['./b2', b2compiler, b2target] 
        }

        // set exec commandLine
        //commandLine cmd.split()
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo', "Command to execute: $cmd"
    }
}
```

#### Background

I am trying to implement a cross-platform Boost C++ build in gradle, where you bootstrap the build, build bcp, use bcp to customize our namespace, and, finally, build each of our boost libraries that we depend on.

Comment: This should be three questions, not one. Also, you should remove everything from the build script that isn't related to the question.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll focus on my primary problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `defaultTasks = boostLibs`, and has to come after declaring `boostLibs`. Alternatively, you can declare a task named `build` that depends on `boostLibs`, and make `"build"` the default task.

Unless you need to access these properties from other build scripts, you can turn them into local variables (e.g. `def boostLibs = ...` instead of `ext.boostLibs = ...`.)

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Don't know why I was over-complicating this.  Thanks for the additional suggestion, in regards to adding a build task.  I hadn't gotten to that step, yet, but this makes sense.  In fact, I still need to create a zip task that will archive the built libs into the project's artifact.  Although, you probably already thought of that. ;-)